# Append series to empty dataframe column always results the same after a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"C": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], "D": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

for i in range(5):
    df["A"] = df["A"].append(df2["C"], ignore_index=True)
```

```
# print(df)

   A    B
0  5  NaN
1  6  NaN
2  7  NaN
3  8  NaN
4  9  NaN
```

As you can see, dataframe `df` is an empty column. After appending `C` column of `df2` to `A` column of `df`, no matter how many times the loop, the `A` column is always `5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.

If we try to append to `B` column of `df` after `A` column, the result is still the same.

```py
for i in range(5):
    df["A"] = df["A"].append(df2["C"], ignore_index=True)
    df["B"] = df["B"].append(df2["D"], ignore_index=True)
```

```
# print(df)

   A    B
0  5  NaN
1  6  NaN
2  7  NaN
3  8  NaN
4  9  NaN
```

If we try to append `df2` to `df`, the result is ok.

```py
for i in range(5):
    df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

```
      A    B    C    D
0   NaN  NaN  5.0  1.0
1   NaN  NaN  6.0  2.0
2   NaN  NaN  7.0  3.0
3   NaN  NaN  8.0  4.0
4   NaN  NaN  9.0  5.0
...
21  NaN  NaN  6.0  2.0
22  NaN  NaN  7.0  3.0
23  NaN  NaN  8.0  4.0
24  NaN  NaN  9.0  5.0
```

Comment: It would be much simpler if you explain what you are trying to achieve with input and expected output.

Comment: @Vishnudev After a 5 loop assignment, IMO, `df["A"]` should have `25` values. Why it only has `5`? Why `df["B"]` is `NaN` after appending values to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** By assigning series to Dataframe column, the series will be conformed to the DataFrames index. The result of `append()` has more elements than the index of `df`, so column value won't change.

There is no problem with the `append()` function, the problem is in `df["A"]` assignment.

With `df["A"] = xx`, we are calling [`__setitem__()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L3147):

```py
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)

        # see if we can slice the rows
        indexer = convert_to_index_sliceable(self, key)
        if indexer is not None:
            # either we have a slice or we have a string that can be converted
            #  to a slice for partial-string date indexing
            return self._setitem_slice(indexer, value)

        if isinstance(key, DataFrame) or getattr(key, "ndim", None) == 2:
            self._setitem_frame(key, value)
        elif isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, list, Index)):
            self._setitem_array(key, value)
        else:
            # set column
            self._set_item(key, value)
```

In this case, we are not accessing the dataframe like `df[:]`, so `indexer` is None. `key` value is `A`, which is just a string type. So we actually call:

```py
self._set_item(key, value)
```

Let's see how [`_set_item()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L3231) is defined:

```py
    def _set_item(self, key, value):
        """
        Add series to DataFrame in specified column.
        If series is a numpy-array (not a Series/TimeSeries), it must be the
        same length as the DataFrames index or an error will be thrown.
        Series/TimeSeries will be conformed to the DataFrames index to
        ensure homogeneity.
        """
        self._ensure_valid_index(value)
        value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
        NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)

        # check if we are modifying a copy
        # try to set first as we want an invalid
        # value exception to occur first
        if len(self):
            self._check_setitem_copy()
```

From the doc, we can see `Series/TimeSeries will be conformed to the DataFrames index to ensure homogeneity.`. This explains why the dataframe `df` doesn't change. Because after the first loop, the result of `append()` is larger than the index of `df`, the redundant is truncated.

If so, why appending to dataframe `df` is successful in the first loop? The answer lays in [`self._ensure_valid_index(value)`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L3284)

```py
    def _ensure_valid_index(self, value):
        """
        Ensure that if we don't have an index, that we can create one from the
        passed value.
        """
```

If the dataframe is empty, this method extends the dataframe to a `len(value)*columns` matrix with `NaN` values. Then with `NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)`, we replace the column `key` with `value`.

In the second example, we are trying to append to `B` column after `A` column:

```py
for i in range(5):
    df["A"] = df["A"].append(df2["C"], ignore_index=True)
    df["B"] = df["B"].append(df2["D"], ignore_index=True)
```

In the first loop, after appending to `A` column, the `B` column of dataframe `df` is filled with `NaN`. `df["B"].append(df2["D"], ignore_index=True)` appends values to original `NaN`. By assigning it to `df["B"]`, the `append()` result will be conformed to the DataFrames index. That's why `df["B"]` remains `NaN`.

In the third example, we just replace the dataframe df with the result of append, it doesn't involve with dataframe `__setitem__()`.

```py
for i in range(5):
    df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: @Vishnudev Yes, I met this question and don't understand why. Trying to search the web, it seems nobody has the same question. After debugging, I think I find the answer. Now share it out, if anyone has the same doubt, this would be a nice start.